# Optional argument passing in c++

Tags: c++, function, arguments

Need's formatting, editing will take some time.

Comment: If function 2 doesn´t change it´s parameter, make it const too and any passing problems will be solved.

Comment: function2 changes only parameter one

Comment: @deviantfan That won't solve the question, he wants to call `function1` with two parameters only once, then call it with just the one changing parameter. So `function1(foo, bar)` for the first call, then `function1(foo)` from there on out, with `bar` somehow magically being valid in `function1` regardless.

Comment: @user2806369 Some concrete code might be helpful. The way your problem is worded right now is somewhat confusing.

Comment: make bar global-one way

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your post with some code per my understanding of the problem. If this code does not properly describe your problem, feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell what you're asking but I'm going to attempt to interpret it as what I read..

```
void function_one(int a, int b = 3);
void function_two(int a);

void function_one(int a, int b)
{
    function_two(b); //pass second argument to function two..
}

void function_two(int a)
{
    function_one(5);
}
```

Note that the above is infinite recursion due not having a base case condition.

Comment: function_one is a part of multithreading,function_one is called by different thred with different values